# How to return gradients for multiple models from a tf.function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I need to obtain gradients for multiple heads of a network (a flexible number), which differ in shape. I am currently using a python list as I have no idea how to solve it. Although it works, it is not recommended within a tf.function as it leads to a performance drop. I tried several solutions, but none of them was successful. Does anyone have any idea how to achieve it otherwise?

```
@tf.function
def train_step(x, y, backbone, *model_heads):
    features = backbone(x)
    all_grads = []
    for i, model_head in enumerate(model_heads):
        y_pred = model_head(features)
        loss_i = loss(y, y_pred)
        scaled_grad = tape.gradient(loss_i, model_head.trainable_variables)
        all_grads.append(optimizer.get_unscaled_gradients(scaled_grad))

    return all_grads


grads = train_step(x, y, backbone, *model_heads)
for i, model_head in enumerate(model_heads):
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads[i], model_head.trainable_variables))
```

Using a python list works, but it affects performance. I also tried TensorArray, but gradients differ in shape as the heads have different architectures